# Creating restful webservice client with jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have the underlisted code to consume a restful webservice, but it always reports an error which is listed below as well. I have tried to using jersey api 1.8 and 1.9 but there isn't any effect.

My Code:

```
public class JerseyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create(); // faulty line

        WebResource resource;

        resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/CustomerApp/webresources/entities.customer");

        String string = resource.path("1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .get(String.class);
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Dec 28, 2012 8:17:06 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException 
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170) 
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) 
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199) 
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:187) at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:159) 
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:669) 
at client.JerseyClient.main(JerseyClient.java:20)
```

Comment: Might sound stupid. Clean and build the project again.

Comment: Which jars are you using?

Comment: I have done that times without number. I had to create the Client With Java.Net.URL. Not that that isn't working fine, its just that i want to explore other means of creating clients.

Comment: The jersey bundle that came with netbeans which was 1.8 but i downloaded 1.9 and it was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Jersey client jar file, maven location for the jersey client is

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->      
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>1.13-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

After this ensure your service running or not and run this client class, it will work well.
You can find the tutorial for creating a restful web service [here](http://www.smashplus.info/2013/04/create-restful-web-service-using-eclipse.html)